# Я решил сделать команду для админов, но не получилось. Можете подсказать в чём проблема?

Tags: discord.py

```
#Кик
@bot.command( pass_context= True )
@commands.has_permissions ( administrator=True )
async def kick ( ctx, member:discord.member, *, reason= None  ):
    await ctx.channel.purge ( limit= 1 )
    await member.kick (reason= reason )


line 476, in _actual_conversion
    raise BadArgument('Converting to "{}" failed for parameter "{}".'.format(name, param.name)) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.BadArgument: Converting to "discord.member" failed for parameter "member".
```

Comment: Попробуйте поменять `discord.member` на `discord.Member`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ты неправильно написал discord.Member, нужно с большой буковки, не с маленькой ;3